# Persist dynamic checkbox state flash builder android app

Tags: android, dynamic, checkbox, flash-builder

Can any one please help me with persisting dynamic checkbox values checked between views in android app using flash builder

```
 for(var i:int=0 ; i<data.PromptText.length; i++)
                {
                 chk = new CheckBox();
                 chk.label= data.PromptText.getItemAt(i);
                 chk.name=data.ResponsePromptID.getItemAt(i);

                 chk.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ClickEvent);
                 chk.width = 1000;
                 chk.height = 50;
                 addElement(chk);}
```

And on my OnClick Event I send the check box data to a database. But, when I change views I am not able to save the check box values. I tried using Persistence Manager, but I am not able to retain the checkbox value. I want to know if there is something like

```
chk.name.selected = SavedState //SavedState = true from my Persistence Manager
```

Please help me, I apologize if I have I confused you.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the link to the answers I had got from one of the other forums. This may help someone 
else

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4887907#4887907